# How can I show a conditional relationship in visual paradigm in an erd project?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd, visual-paradigm

I wanna draw an ERD to show, give a discount to the customer already made an account else nothing happens, how  can I show it in visual paradigm?

Comment: Customer 1..1 --- 0..1 Customer Discount